# Memory optimized table - Partially load data into memory

Tags: sql-server, memory-optimized-tables

Is it possible for a memory optimized table in SQL server to have part of its data in memory and the rest on disk?

I have a requirement to load the last 3 months' data into memory, and the rest
of it isn't really required to be in memory because it will not be
queried.

Is there any way to do this with memory optimized tables? If not, is there any alternate way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered partitioning the table, frequently accessed partitions will reside in the data cache without requiring memory optimized tables.

Comment: @SteveFord Frequently accessed partitions will only remain in cache unless they are evicted due to memory pressure. There is no longer any guarantee of anything remaining in hot buffers since DBCC PINTABLE was removed. The only option that provides a guarantee is Memory-Optimized Tables. It's a well-accepted pattern at this point to have a strategy where hot data is in Memory-Optimized tables, and so-called 'cold' data is on disk. A UNION ALL view, similar to what we had with 'partitioned views' way back when, ties the data together. Application logic can also do this.

Answer (score 2):

Use a view to union an in-memory table with a standard table (a partitioned view).  Run a maintenance process to move data from the in-memory table to the standard table as needed.

You can add check-constraints to the standard table to help eliminate it from the query if that data will not be touched.

Comment: This answer is the way to go. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/application-pattern-for-partitioning-memory-optimized-tables

Answer (score 1):

The database can have few tables on disk and few in memory,but it is not possible to have ,some of table data in disk and some data in memory

> I have a requirement to load the last 3 months' data into memory, and the rest of it isn't really required to be in memory because it will not be queried

why not archive the table regularly ,so it retains only three months data  and optimize it for In-memory usage..